# Subtraction loops in java

Tags: java, loops, subtraction

I am new to java and am stuck on this challenge. I am to calculate the state of water depending on the inputed temp and altitude. However, for every 300 metres (for altitude) the boiling point is to drop by 1 degree. I am confused as to how to make it a loop that will take one off for every three hundred rather than just removing one when it hits three hundred. This is what I have so far.
EDIT: Thank you so much for the help! Didn't even know if people used this website anymore but now I will use it all the time lol :D

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WaterState
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the temperature then the altitude separated by one or more spaces");
        double temperature = scan.nextDouble();
        double altitude = scan.nextDouble();
        double bp = 100;
        if (temperature <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is solid at the given conditions");
        }
        if (temperature >= 1 && temperature < 100)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is liquid at the given conditions");
        }
        if (temperature >= 100)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is gas at the given conditions");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Divide the altitude by 300 to get the number of degrees to drop. Since you're dealing in doubles I guess you'd want 150m to drop half a degree? You absolutely don't want to be using loops here.

Comment: It's very tempting for new developers to assume loops are involved whenever they hear "for every", but it's very frequently just math, as it is in this example.

Comment: @Joha the answer you deleted is a fair point, and you can see in the code here there's a gap for temperature >0 and <1 since temperature is a double, but I don't think that's the problem here. (wasn't my downvote!)

Comment: I believe I don't want 150m to drop half a degree. The challenge states it should only drop every 300m but I'm not sure. I'll copy it into the comments here

Comment: "Write a program (let’s call it WaterState) which reads in temperature (in degrees Celsius) and altitude (in metres above sea level) and reports whether water is solid, liquid, or gaseous at the given conditions. Assume that the boiling point of water goes down by 1 degree for each 300m rise in altitude, and that the freezing point is unaffected by altitude. Also, assume that altitude cannot be negative."

Comment: I modified my answer. Now it only updates the temperature in discrete amounts (casting the altitude to an integer instead of double), does not change the freezing point, and ensures that the altitude is at least zero. There are other ways to convert the altitude to an integer. If you want, you can check out another approaches here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-double-to-integer-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think a loop is needed to calculate the boiling point? Think about it: given an altitude, return the boiling point of water. You can actually calculate the melting and boiling points with this info and then just check in which range you fall in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WaterState
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the temperature then the altitude separated by one or more spaces");
        double temperature = scan.nextDouble();
        double altitude = scan.nextDouble();

        double offset = (int)altitude / 300.0;
        double boilingPoint = 100 - offset;
        double freezePoint = 0 - offset;
        if (temperature <= freezePoint)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is solid at the given conditions");
        }
        if (temperature > freezePoint  && temperature < boilingPoint)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is liquid at the given conditions");
        }
        if (temperature >= boilingPoint)
        {
            System.out.println ("Water is gas at the given conditions");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We should check altitude < 0 also. Boiling point may hardly be > 100. Or set 100, if altitude < 0. And why freezingPoint may be less than 0?

Comment: I don't think altitude affects the freezing point like that, only the boiling point.

Comment: No idea about any of that to be sincere. If you feel confident about it, feel free to edit the answer ;)

Comment: That's genius!! Thank you so so much :))

Comment: How would you write that out?

Comment: Okay great! Tysm